# How does a DC brushless drill-driver work?

Tags: dc-motor, speed

My new cordless, brushless drill has good torque, but it won't turn below about 50 rpm. My older brush-type drill, same model, will drive screws even at near-zero speed. Does the brushless circuit need a minumum speed to work properly?

Comment: You can google this answer in many places. Furthemore, this is is far too broad a question to ask here.

Comment: This is a vague question and it could require a very long response. Was there something specific you were uncertain about? Right now, your question "How does XYZ work" is like asking how a car works, etc.

Comment: what's a drill-driver? Is that a fancy word for a motor used in a drill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A BLDC motor receives a 3 phase signal from the motor driver, such that the current flowing in the stator coils produces a torque in the permanent magnet rotor. This requires that the motor driver knows, or can estimate, the position of the rotor with respect to the stator.

There are two ways to estimate the rotor position.

There's the expensive way, used in motors that must run down to zero speed, like wheel motors in Segways and hover boards. These use Hall effect sensors in the stator to sense the position of the magnets in the rotor. Motors tend to have 6 wires coming from them, three fat, three thin.

And then there's the cheap way, used in motors that are only required to run as motors, like propeller motors for drones. These rely on the motion of the rotor to induce voltages in the stator coils. The motor driver senses these, to infer where the rotor is. These motors just have three fat wires. As the voltage is proportional to speed, this method needs a certain minimum speed to generate a large enough signal to sense properly above the noise. The motor is started by driving it as a stepper motor for a few steps, to get it up to an adequate speed.

It sounds like you've got one that's built the cheap way.

I'd be happy with a *drill* that didn't produce torque at stall, but I'm often using my (old skool brushed motor) drill as a *screwdriver* right down to zero speed, and it's essential that it still produces torque at stall. I wondered if there was a down side to brushless drills. I wonder if the more expensive drills do work when stalled? I would have expected a brushless *screwdriver* to work to zero speed, it's a bit of a chocolate teapot if it doesn't.